# Перегрузка оператора ввода для заполнения двумерного массива

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Подскажите пожалуйста, где моя ошибка.Реализовал класс с двумерным динамическим массивом. Кол-во колонок и полей задается через конструктор. Проблема возникает когда я пытаюсь перегрузить оператор ввода подобным образом:

```
friend IntArr& operator >> (istream &in, IntArr& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
            in >> a.pa[i][j];
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Вот сам класс:

```
class IntArr {
    friend IntArr& operator >> (istream &in, IntArr& a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
                in >> a.pa[i][j];
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
private:
    int **pa;
    int rows, cols;
public:
    IntArr() {
        pa = 0; rows = 0; cols = 0;
    }
    IntArr(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows; this->cols = cols;
        float **pa = new float*[this->rows]; // две строки 
        for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
            pa[count] = new float[this->cols]; // и пять столбцов
    }
};
```

Comment: "Проблема возникает..." Какая проблема??? В приведенном коде почти все сделано правильно, кроме странного числа 2 в цикле выделения памяти. Откуда взялось 2? В комментарии написано "две строки и пять столбцов". Откуда вдруг взялись "две строки и пять столбцов" если вам даны переменные количества строк и столбцов?

Answer (score 1):

В C++ есть только одномерные массивы, а `pa` - это указатель на массив с указателями. В конструкторе `IntArr` вы объявляете локальную переменную `float **pa`, с тем же именем, что и поле класса, все поля класса остаются неинициализированны. Должно быть как-то так (опуская вопросы последующего освобождения памяти):

```
private: int ** m_pa;
private: int m_rows;
private: int m_cols;

public: explicit
IntArr(void): m_pa{}, m_rows{}, m_cols{} {}

public: explicit
IntArr(int rows, int cols): m_pa{new float *[rows]}, m_rows{rows}, m_cols{cols}
{
    for (int row_index{0}; row_index < rows; ++row_index)
    {
       m_pa[row_index] = new float[cols];
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного непонятен ваши записи. Вы используете новые стандарты языка?

Comment: @I.Bilous Нет, все в рамках С++11. А если не использовать list initialization, то и в рамках C++03.

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Просто такие записи первый раз вижу. Сейчас буду разбираться)

Answer (score 0):

```
 friend IntArr& operator >> (istream &in, IntArr& a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
                in >> a.pa[i][j];
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
```

вы  обьект `istream` возвращаете как  `IntArr`
Нужно  написать

```
friend istream& operator>>...
```