# Проблема при заполнении динамического массива через перегруженный оператор

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс для представления двумерного динамического массива. Кол-во колонок и столбцов указывается через конструктор, там же и выделяется динамическая память. Далее массив должен заполняться с клавиатуры через перегруженный оператор ввода, но происходит ошибка: Exception thrown: read access violation.
[image: Ошибка при отладке]

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

class IntArr {
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &in, IntArr& a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
                in >> a.pa[i][j];
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
private:
    int **pa;
    int rows, cols;
public:
    IntArr() {
        pa = 0; rows = 0; cols = 0;
    }
    IntArr(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows; this->cols = cols;
        int **pa = new int*[this->rows]; // две строки 
        for (int count = 0; count < this->rows; count++) {
            pa[count] = new int[this->cols]; // и пять столбцов
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    IntArr first(3, 4);
    cin >> first;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Буду благодарен за указанную помощь

Comment: я бы размещал бы одномерный массив и определил бы операторы индекса (нужен будет доп.. класс для имитации двумерности)  таким образом только одна операция размещения на вызов конструктора и массив будет монолитным

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783487/Перегрузка-оператора-ввода-для-заполнения-двумерного-массива).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вы выделяете память -

```
int **pa = new int*[this->rows]; // две строки
```

и все бы ничего, если не считать, что при выходе из функции вы получаете утечку памяти... только при этом вот этот член

```
private:
    int **pa;
```

оказывается ни при чем, не получая никакого значения. А потом вы пытаетесь его разыменовывать...

Comment: Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Неужели непонятно? Для начала убрать `int**` при `pa` в `IntArr(int rows, int cols)`...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ